# Why rename doesn't work?

Tags: python, string, escaping

The following rename command of directory works fine

```
os.rename("4\347\357\344","newname")
```

However, this one fails, telling "No such file or directory"

```
xxx = "4\%d\%d\%d" % (347, 357, 344)
os.rename(xxx, "newname")
```

I also tried following and it failed

```
xxx = "4" + "\\" + str(int(s1)) + "\\" + str(int(s2)) + "\\" + str(int(s3))
```

Last 2 ways are constructing same string as first literal, if I print. So why they don't work?

Comment: Those strings aren't the same. The first string `repr`s to `4\xe7\xef\xe4`, the second one to `4\\347\\357\\344`.

Comment: So how to modify last 2 examples to make it same?

Comment: `'4'+''.join(chr(int(str(n), 8)) for n in (347, 357, 344))`

Comment: why is "\347" becoming "\xe7"?

Comment: @Daniel Octal 347 equals hex e7. Seee my answer.

Comment: @ David Heffernan, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second example does not escape:
`"4\%d\%d\%d" % (347, 357, 344)` yields `4\\347\\357\\344`

The first one does, yielding `4\xe7\xef\xe4`

The last one also does not escape.

**UPDATE**
To get the result you are seeking, try

`'4'+''.join([chr(int(str(z),8)) for z in [347, 357, 344]])`

Comment: `xxx = "4\\%d\\%d\\%d" % (347, 357, 344)` doesn't work either, same error `No such file or directory`

Comment: @Pablo this does not escape either; what is the exact filename you are trying to produce?

Comment: exact file name is in unknown codepage, which I don't have to detect and that is not a task. `ls -b` on terminal reveals the file name in C style escaped sequence as in first example, which I need to construct.

Answer (score 0):

```
"4\347\357\344"
```

This literal contains escaped octal sequences. The other strings do not and are different.

```
>>> s1 = "4\347\357\344"
>>> s2 = "4\%d\%d\%d" % (347, 357, 344)
>>> print s1 == s2
False
>>> print repr(s1)
'4\xe7\xef\xe4'
>>> print repr(s2)
'4\\347\\357\\344'
```

As you can see, `s1` and `s2` are not equal. As for the representation of `s1`, octal 347 is equal to hexadecimal e7. And so on.

In summary, `os.rename` works, but your strings differ.

Comment: So how to escape properly `\\` to get the same result?

Comment: I do not understand that question